# SQL Server: If a row is inserted in one table, how do I write a trigger to insert that same row in a different table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, insert, row

I'm not sure how to create this trigger,.I need to add a row in pub_info table when a row is inserted in publishers table. The exact same row. SQL server

```
CREATE TRIGGER checkCity
ON pub_info
AFTER INSERT
AS
IF -- a row is inserted into publishers table, 
   -- how do I add the same row into pub_info table?
INSERT VALUES(@pub_id, NULL, 'new publishers')
BEGIN
END;
```

Comment: people would need your DBMS name tagged in order to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a trigger on `publishers` table and not on `pub_info` .
The inserted data is available in the [INSERTED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) table in the trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER checkCity
ON publishers
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO pub_info(pubid, pubname, pub_description)
      SELECT pubid, pubname, pub_description 
      FROM INSERTED;
END;
```

Comment: I would think the check `IF EXISTS()` is really not needed, because the trigger will only ever fire **IF** an `INSERT` statement has been executed, and in such a case, at least one row **must exist** in the `Inserted` table. And even if it didn't - the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ` would not do anything "wrong" or error out, if `Inserted` doesn't contain any rows

Comment: @marc_s careful what you assume. a trigger will fire even if zero rows are inserted. Won't make a difference in this case but it might in others.